# How to successfully pass an IV from Python to Java (Encryption)?

Tags: python, java, encryption

I'm trying to figure out the best way to encrypt and decrypt some JSON data that I'm passing from my client (Python) to server (Java). I keep running into a few errors. Originally I had a set IV that I had hardcoded into both client and server and it was working great, it would encrypt and decrypt as I needed. However, that's obviously a bad idea, I set a random IV that I would then slice with my server and that sorta worked. It would decrpyt most of the data, except for the first 50 bytes or so. They would just be random chars `(�6OC�Ղ�{�9��aJ, "number": 1243.2,`...etc) and I couldn't parse the JSON.

Then when I try to slice OFF the IV (16 chars) from the decoded bytes I get an error saying that the data needs to be in multiples of 16, but I'm not sure why that isn't working.

Any ideas on how to get this working? Thanks!

**Python Client**

```
       jsonString = json.dumps(data.__dict__, default=str)

        key = 'sixteenssixteens'
        text = jsonString
        plaintext = self.pad(text)

        iv = os.urandom(16)

        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        encrpyt_btye = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
        encrpyt_text = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(encrpyt_btye).decode("UTF-8")

        requests.post('server', data=encrpy_text)

    def pad(self, text):
        numberBytestoPad = block_size - len(text) % block_size
        ascii_string = chr(numberBytestoPad)
        padding_str = numberBytestoPad * ascii_string
        padded_text = text + padding_str
        return padded_text
```

**Java Server**

```
  requestBody = exchange.getRequestBody();
            String requestData = readString(requestBody);
            System.out.println(requestData);

            String key = "sixteenssixteens";
            String initVector = requestData.substring(0, 16);

            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            try {

               //Tried to remove the IV from the start of the string
               // String removeIV = requestData.substring(16);

                Cipher cipherd = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
                cipherd.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
                byte[] original = cipherd.doFinal(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(requestData));
                String decryptedResult = new String(original);
                System.out.println("Decrypted string: " + decryptedResult);
                try {
                    data = gson.fromJson(decryptedResult, Data.class);
                } catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: As the IV does not need to be kept secret just prepend the IV to the ciphertext before Base64 encoding. On decryption side Base64-decode the data and strip off the first 16 bytes and use them as IV.

Comment: Please make sure you actually understand encoding / decoding - bytes and byte representations. The IV doesn't consist of 16 **characters**, it consists of 16 bytes. Similarly, a key should never be represented as a string, that would be a **password** (and you'd need a PBKDF to derive a key from a password). If you do a POST you can send/receive binary data perfectly fine, so the base 64 encoding isn't even necessary.

Comment: Note that using CBC makes you directly vulnerable against padding oracle attack. Above is nice as an exercise, but if you'd use it in an actual protocol you'd have about zero protection against hackers that know anything about cryptography. Pretty please with sugar on top: use TLS for actual protection.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, I'm not keeping that as a my key, it was just an example. Thank you for the feedback, I was going to use both TLS and this for protection. I didn't realize that CBC was vulnerable like that, is there a different protocol that you recommend?